# Portable and custom server.xml for app?

Tags: java, xml, maven, tomcat, ssl

I configured my `server.xml` for using SSL. But I want to make portable configuration and store it in `.war` file.

Is it possible to provide custom `server.xml` during my `.war` file deployment? May be exists something like

```
-Dcatalina.config = src/main/resources/server.xml
```

Or storing config in `pom.xml`?

Or any way to dynamically provide SSL connector for my app deployment?

One possible way - using **maven-tomcat-plugin**, but it's not appropriate for me

Any idea?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can provide webapp specific xml files which will be incorporated into the effective server.xml by Tomcat.  You might go through the Tomcat documentation, or the comments in the default server.xml file, to find the details.